# How to construct neo4j and lucene files permanently?

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

I will process **~20GB** data and construct `lucene` and `neo4j` files of them. It takes approximately `30 hours` to process. The important thing is to construct them once and work one them (i.e writing queries etc) later. 
How is it possible to construct those files once use them whenever I want?

Comment: Can you clarify?  If you do the 30 hours of processing, the result should be a database.  So then you only have to do it once.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Is it possible to do same thing for the lucene files?

Comment: If you use legacy indexes inside of neo4j, those legacy indexes are built via lucene.  Hence your database will include "lucent files" in the database dir.  So yes -- if you build a DB with legacy indexes, those lucene files would be included.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits your answer was helpful. Thanks :)